# Can not access a function in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

How can I access a function **drawCustomMenuBlock()** in the file

> Eternal\CustomMenu\Eternal\CustomMenu\Block\Catalog\Navigation.php, wants to access these function in the page app\design\frontend\zonda\default\template\page\html\header.phtml. But if I place these code in the file

```
<?php echo $this->drawCustomMenuBlock() ?>
```

Then it shows this error :

```
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
```

How can I solve this ?
Please help me out of this. I am new in Magento.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside phtml file, $this means instance of that block.

Example: page\html\header.phtml, **$this** is the instance of **app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php**.

So create you a method called "**drawCustomMenuBlock**" inside **app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php**, then you call from **page\html\header.phtml**.

Try it.

Comment: I had tried this before. The drawCustomMenuBlock is alredy inside the page app\code\local\Eternal\CustomMenu\Block\Catalog\Navigation.php page. But when i copy this function inside this page then it shows error.

Comment: As per I know "app\code\local\Eternal\CustomMenu\Block\Catalog\Navigation.php page" block related to template "catalog/navigation/left.phtml"

Comment: Yah you are right. This drawCustomMenuBlock function is written in the Navigation.php file and this function is called from template\eternal\custommenu\top.phtml file.

Comment: Actually my requirement is in the header panel there are 4 menus among them one is custommenublock shows right side in the menu panel. This custommenublock have to seperate and  place it left side of this panle and remaining menus will show on the right side.